# How do I make this CSS layout work?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the .e div in the .second div up by 50%. My goal is to get rid of the white space between the two .e divs.

I want to do this without explicitly moving the div up (ex. position: relative; top: -50%;). I noticed that doing float: right; on the .first div fixes the layout issue, but destroys the order of the HTML contents.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do: 
[image]

**How can I make this work while keeping my html in the same order?**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body .a {
  background: #f04576;
}
body .b {
  background: #53a2e3;
}
body .c {
  background: #ef4658;
  text-align: right;
}
body .d {
  background: #f4ad49;
  text-align: left;
}
body .e {
  background: #69de92;
}
body .first {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body .second {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body .tall:nth-child(2n) {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
body .tall, body .long, body .square {
  float: left;
}
body .tall {
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body .long {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(50% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body .square {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
```

**Edit 1:** 
I don't want to do `position: relative; top: -50%;`, because if I repeat my HTML, I'm left with a giant gap after each .second div. Here's an example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body .a {
  background: #f04576;
}

body .b {
  background: #53a2e3;
}

body .c {
  background: #ef4658;
  text-align: right;
}

body .d {
  background: #f4ad49;
  text-align: left;
}

body .e {
  background: #69de92;
}

body .first {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body .second {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body .tall:nth-child(2n) {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}

body .tall,
body .long,
body .square {
  float: left;
}

body .tall {
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body .long {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(50% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body .square {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
<!-- Repeating the code -->
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use positioning?

Comment: A gap remains after every .second div if I repeat my HTML.

Comment: My solution fixes that. Repeated it 8 times and no whitespace.

Comment: Can you add other html elements?

Comment: Sure, but I'd prefer not to. I want my HTML to be strictly content and my CSS to handle all of the styling (like layout and positioning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this code:

```
body .tall:nth-child(2n) {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
```

to

```
body .second .tall {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
```

or to

```
body .second .tall {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body .a {
  background: #f04576;
}
body .b {
  background: #53a2e3;
}
body .c {
  background: #ef4658;
  text-align: right;
}
body .d {
  background: #f4ad49;
  text-align: left;
}
body .e {
  background: #69de92;
}
body .first {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body .second {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body .second .tall {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
body .tall, body .long, body .square {
  float: left;
}
body .tall {
  height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body .long {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(50% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body .square {
  height: calc(50% - 4rem);
  width: calc(25% - 4rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
<!-- Repeating the code -->
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>

<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
<!-- Repeating the code -->
<div class='first'>
  <div class='a tall'>A</div>
  <div class='c square'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d long'>D</div>
  <div class='e square'>E</div>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <div class='a square'>A</div>
  <div class='c long'>B</div>
  <div class='b long'>C</div>
  <div class='d square'>D</div>
  <div class='e tall'>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I want to do this without explicitly moving the div up (ex. position: relative; top: -50%;)"_

Comment: Thanks Chris! Works perfectly.

Comment: @DeepDuggal With all due respect, why did you bother saying you didn't want a solution that moved the element upward if you were perfectly fine with a solution that does just that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. Unfortunately, I believe that the answer to your question, with the constraints you have provided, is that it cannot be done.

There is no CSS style that will cause elements to adjust themselves vertically to fill empty space. No matter what you do, the C block is going to wrap to the following line, and further blocks will be appended after it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using flexbox. CSS Grid will probably be the perfect solution for your problem, but since that is not ready, a flexbox-based layout could work better than what you currently have. You could pretty significantly reduce the complexity of your layout. Just as a partial example:

```css
.a {
  background: #f04576;
  flex: 1;
}
.b {
  background: #53a2e3;
  flex: 3;
}
.c {
  background: #ef4658;
  flex: 4;
}
.d {
  background: #f4ad49;
  flex: 1;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  height:100vh;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.left-top, .left-bot {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
}
.e {
  background: #69de92;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>

  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-top">
      <div class='a '>A</div>
      <div class='c '>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-bot">
      <div class='b '>C</div>
      <div class='d '>D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='e'>E</div>
  
</div>
```